# Shopify cart should remove all bundle products if one product form that bundle is removed

Tags: shopify, cart, shopify-app

I have make custom bundles in shopify without use of any app. When I click on add to cart all those buld products are moved to cart but on cart there is not any specific if or data-bundle that is common in all these product which i can used to remove all products from cart if one of them is removed.
I am adding the product inside the cart using this script

```
$('.add_to_cart_btn').on('click',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var prod_id = $(this).data('id');
var counter_sec = 0;
var open_crt = false;
var total = $('.variant_outer').length;
$('.variant_outer.grinding').each(function(index){
var qty = $(this).find('.qtybox').find('input').val();
if(qty >= 1){
  open_crt = true
  return false;
}
});
setTimeout(function(){
if(open_crt){
  var value = $('input[name="commercial"]:checked').val();
  if(value == 'yes'){
    value = 'For Commercial Use'
  }else{
    value = '';
  }
  if(value != ''){
    var data_value = {id:prod_id,quantity:1,properties:{"Commercial":value}};
  }else{
    var data_value = {id:prod_id,quantity:1};
  }
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:'/cart/add.js',
    dataType:'json',
    data:data_value,
    async:false,
    success:function(cart){
      if(value == 'yes'){
        $.post('/cart/update.js',{attributes:{"customAttributes":"For Commercial Use"}},function() 
    {},'json')
      }
    }
   });
   $('.variant_outer').each(function(index){
    var qty = $(this).find('.qtybox').find('input').val();
    if(qty >= 1){
      var ids = $(this).find('.qtybox').data('id');
      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:'/cart/add.js',
        dataType:'json',
        data:{id:ids,quantity:qty},
        async:false,
        success:function(cart){
        }
      })
     }
     if(index == total - 1){
      cartDrawer();
    }
    })
   }else{
   $.fancybox.open({
    src:"#grinding_popup"
   })
  }
  },1500); 
 });
```

Comment: hi, can give me some details what exactly you like to achieve? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do bundles is to take advantage of product line item properties. Using those, you can tie a bundle together. Use that in the cart update code. If a product from the bundle is removed, you can look in the line item properties for the connecting glue to the other products in the bundle. Remove them too. It is pretty straightforward and ensures your bundling makes some sense.